# how can filter data depending on another model in Django admin

Tags: python, django, filter

> models.py

```
class Destination(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200,db_index=True, null=True)



class City(models.Model):
            destination = models.ForeignKey(Destination, related_name='des_city', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
            title = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True, null=True)



 class Program(models.Model):
            destination = models.ForeignKey(Destination, related_name='des_programs', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
            city = models.ForeignKey(City, related_name='cit_programs', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
            title = models.CharField(max_length=300, db_index=True, null=True)
```

> admin.py

```
  class ProgramAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
            model = Program

    admin.site.register(Destination)
    admin.site.register(Program, ProgramAdmin)
    admin.site.register(City)
```

> if it possible in admin area in program model we select first the
>   destination as country and then city belong to only one destination 
>   example destination E
>   gypt  then drop-down menu in city with all cities
>   belong to egypt like Hurghada, Sharm Elshikh et.

Comment: probably this https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html ?

Comment: this only in client side but not working in Django Admin